# Adding word to String using print slices and concatenation

Tags: string, printing, concatenation, slice

How to achieve the result of the following with the added word *humanly in a print function?

> ’Be as happy as possible’
>
> ’Be as happy as humanly possible’

Comment: Can you let us know in which language this is?

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick.

```
var str = 'be as happy as possible';
var newStr = str.split(' ');
newStr[3] = newStr[3] + ' humanly '
console.log(newStr)
```